# How to highlight non-existent resource field name in custom view model attribute constructor in Visual Studio 2012 text editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resources, resharper, custom-attributes

Let me be more specific. When I create some view model in **ASP .Net MVC** application and define `Display` attribute for some field using resources and if I enter resource field name incorrectly I get it red highlighted like on the screen shot below:

[image]

I created custom `Description` attribute to provide more detailed information about current Model property to view like below:

```
using System;
using System.Resources;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ...
{
    public class DescriptionAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
    {
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public Type ResourceType { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            if (ResourceType == null) return;
            var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);
            metadata.Description = resourceManager.GetString(Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But, the thing is, when I use non-existent resource field name when define this attribute I don't get it red highlighted like in case with Display attribute.

[image]

I tried to google but I'm not sure that google understands me correctly or that I express myself to google correctly. What should I do to make text editor highlight such type of errors for me? I use Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper.

P.S. To avoid questions like "Why don't you use `[Display(... Name = "Name", Description = "Description")]` ?" I'll say that I have custom `Html.DescriptionFor()` helper method, which is tied to this attribute, and override or change original MVC's one `Html.DisplayDescription()` is not recommended by our inner team practices.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this highlight is by custom code. ReSharper has a "reference provider" that creates a reference from the string literal of the `Name` property to a node in the abstract syntax tree for the type specified in `ResourceType`. If the property in the string literal doesn't exist, the reference is invalid, and displayed, in red, as an error. If the property does exist, the reference is created and the string literal shows up in find usages and is renamed when the underlying property on the `ResourceType` is renamed.

You can write your own plugin that can implement a reference provider, and base it on the code that ReSharper uses. Fire up [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and find the type called `DisplayNameAttributePropertyNameReferenceFactory` (note the inner class `Factory` that's marked with a `ReferenceProviderFactoryAttribute`, this is how you tell ReSharper about the reference provider).